# Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the following error :

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type '----.Messagetypes' is less
>
> accessible than method '---.MessageBox---.Messagetypes, string)'

my code :

```
public partial class Global
{
    private  enum Messagetypes { Error };

    public  void MessageBox(Messagetypes MessageDisplay, string MessageError)
    {

    }
}
```

What is the correct code

Comment: In the future post the exact error including the line number, and then supply the class the error is in, otherwise its hard to help you.  I do not believe you can even declare an emumeration as private.

Comment: @Ramhound It seems like you actually can, I wrote `private enum MyEnum{ one, two}` in a class and it compiled fine, contrary to what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) says.

Comment: @Rahmhound Why would you not be able to declare an enumeration as private?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Messagetypes` is private, but is a parameter to a `public` function. The only people that would ever be able to call it are other `private` members.  Either change your function to `private`, or change your `enum` to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `Messagetype` be private since apparently your application is trying to use it outside of the `Global` class. Change it to `public` and it should work.

Comment: internal won't work.  It has to be the same accessibility or more accessible