# C# Returning List - Inconsistent Accessibility

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistent accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959621/inconsistent-accessibility)

When I try returning a `List<MyType>` in one of my methods to something calling it from another class, it is giving me the following error:

Inconsistent accessibility: return type `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyType>` is less accessible than method `MyMethod(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)`

Any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: What is the generic type of the List? Would be good if you provide the code

Comment: It was because I forgot to declare class MyType public. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, pretty much just like it says. You probably have a `List<SomeInternalClass>` and you are returning that `List<SomeInternalClass>` from a *PUBLIC* method. So, the compiler is telling you that even though people can see this method, they CAN'T see the type you are trying to return. You will need to make your Method or your type both internal or both public.

Example:

```
internal class Foo {
}
public class Class1
{
    public List<Foo> Bar() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when your method is returning a generic list of `MyType` that is less accessible than the method returning it, for example

```
public class TestClass {
    public List<MyClass> MyMethod() {
        return new List<MyClass>();
    }
    private class MyClass {
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }
}
```