# Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sample.sheet.Order>' is less accessible than method 'getData()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to convert datatable to list and retrun as list but throws the exception

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sample.sheet.Order>' is less accessible than method 'Sample.Features.getData()'

.

```
        [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Order> getData()
    {
       DataTable ds = getDataSource();
       List<Order> listdata = new List<Order>();
       for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           Order ord = new Order();
           ord.CustomerID = (int)ds.Rows[i]["CustomerID"];
           listdata.Add(ord);
       }
       return listdata;
    }
```

Please suggest me., what i did wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Returning List - Inconsistent Accessibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344848/c-sharp-returning-list-inconsistent-accessibility)

Comment: Is `Order` is a public class?

Comment: No its an `internal`. Now i changed it to `public ` which solves my problem. thanks.

Comment: @Raja why you removed the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the **`Order`** public class.

Your Order class is less accessible than the method. You should check that Orderis not private/internal

Comment: No this is not correct, `getData` is a web method so it should be `static`. @upvoter please take care while voting