# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IInventoryServices' is less accessible than method

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

IInventoryServices is less accessible than method InventoryController.InventoryController(IInventoryServices)   WebApplication.Api

```
public class InventoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IInventoryServices _services;

        public InventoryController(IInventoryServices services)
        {
            _services = services;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959621/inconsistent-accessibility)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your IInventoryServices interface is not `public`. When you don't specify an [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) for an interface, it defaults to "internal".

The complaint is because although your InventoryController class is `public` (=accessible to any code), the parameters of the constructor are restricted.